# RSpec Spy method issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, tdd

```
it "calls #create if #find_or_create is called and no matching record exists" do
  snack = class_spy(Snack, find_by_name: nil)
  attrs = {name: 'test', location: 'test'}
  snack.find_or_create(attrs)
  expect(snack).to have_received(:create).with(attrs)
end
```

and within the Snack class

```
def self.find_or_create(attrs)
  snack = find_by_name(attrs[:name])
  snack ||= create(attrs)
end
```

However create doesn't seem to be getting called--I guess is this expected?/Any thoughts as to that for which I had not accounted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, you can just do it like this:

```
it 'whatewer' do
  expect(Snack).to receive(:create).with(attrs)
  Snack.find_or_create(attrs)
end
```